# How to delete application on button press.?

Tags: c#

So, I am trying to figure out how you can delete the `exe` from your desktop after you have closed the application.

I know how to exit the application `Application.Exit();`

But I just need to know how to delete the application after the `button press + Application.Exit()`

Comment: hi xLeak, can you please confirm if the solution below answered your question, if yes, it would be great if you can mark it as answered by clicking the green tick box

Answer (score 2):

Invokes the Delete Operation in a deferred fashion through the command Line

```
 private static void DeleteApp()
        {

            Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                Arguments = "/C choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 3 & Del \"" + Application.ExecutablePath + "\"",
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                FileName = "cmd.exe"
            });
        }
```

You can Invoke `DeleteApp()` in your Window `Closing` event handler like this

***.xaml***

```
  <Window x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow"

  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp"  WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
   Closing="Window_Closing"

  Title="TestApp" Width="700" Height="500">
```

***.cs***

```
    private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {

       DeleteApp();
    }
```

Comment: wouldn't that fail because the app would still be running by then?

Comment: @jalsh, Nope if you take a closer look at the DeleteApp(), it invokes a cmd process with a delay of 3 sec. That takes care of deleting the exe after it has exited

Comment: hello xLeak, If the answer helped with your question, please accept the answer by clicking the green tick box next to it